# Construct an explicit function $f : (0, \infty) \rightarrow (0, 1)$ such that $\forall\ x\ \in\ (0, \infty),\, 2 – f(x) < x$

Tags: functions

I tried $f(x) = \frac{1}{\pi}( \text{tan}^{-1}(x) + \frac{\pi}{2})$ but the condition that $2 – f(x) < x$ only holds for $x > 1.2187$

Comment: Are you sure you have the problem stated correctly? How can this ever be true for x = 0.5? For x = 0.5, you have $2 - f(0.5) < 0.5$. That implies that $f(0.5) > 1.5$. But the range of $f$ is supposedly only $(0,1)$

Answer (score 3):

Assume that

$$(\forall x>0)\;\; f(x)>2-x$$

then

$$f(1)>1$$

So, it is not possible that the range is $ (0,1)$.